# Will vsdoc files work for vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, visual-studio-2010, vsdoc

In an attempt to create better intellisense support for legacy classic asp / vbscript, will the visual studios vsdoc files work for other scripting laguages e.g. vbscript?

### EDIT

Thanks for Rodolfo answer, it also helped me clarify my question: I hoping that vsdoc files will help provide better intellisense for include files.

Comment: Is this answered? I think it is. If so, please, mark Rodolfo's answer as correct or add your own.

Comment: Hi @rcdmk thanks for bringing this back to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

I know you can use VS2008 SP1 for ASP/vbscript files with perfect intellisense, not sure about VS2010.
It even works with functions/subs defined in the same file, but alas, it doesn't read include files (would be magical if it did)

Comment: Hi @Rodolfo thanks for the answer, good point on the intellisence from within the same file. I'm hoping that vsdoc file to help get around the problem of not doing intellisense for include files.